# Can two different electrons superimpose or be at the same place?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We know that two different waves can be at the same place, and that electrons show both wave and particle nature, so can two electrons superimpose or be at the same place?

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually you cannot simply add waves, as there is an interaction between the two electrons.

Electrons are identical particles. You cannot distinguish between electron 1 and electron 2. Say, electron 1 sits at x1 and electron 2 sits at x2. Placing electron 1 at x2 and simultaneosly placing electron 2 at x1 should not change anything, because you still have one electron at x1 and another one at x2. This can be expressed as $\Psi\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\pm\Psi\left(x_2,x_1\right)$ (the $\pm$ come from the fact that we are only interested in the probabilities, and not in the probability amplitude). The $\pm$ also implies that the wave-function is either symmetric or anti-symmetric.

Electrons are fermions, it follows from quantum field theory (but afaik not from quantum mechanics) that fermions must have an anti-symmetric wave function. For the wave function of two particles to by anti-symmetric the two components must differ in any anti-symmetric way. In case of the electrons this is their spin. So YES, electrons can be at the same position, but their spin must differ!

Comment: This is, of course, neglecting things like electrostatic repulsion, degeneracy pressure, or the fact that there is always uncertainty in any position measurement?

Comment: I do not think that degeneracy pressure is neglected here. This particulary pressure only comes from the Pauli principle and only applies to EQUAL fermions - two electrons with opposite spin aren't equal, because they differe in one observable - THEIR SPIN.

Comment: What about the other things?

Comment: Also, uncertainty is not neglected. You just can't know $\Delta x \Delta p$ better than $h$, but you can, in principle, know $x$ with absolute certainty - but then you don't know anything about the momentum. But as long as you don't care about $p$ anyways, no harm is done in that.

Comment: This also explains why the coulomb potential could be ignored here, because if $p$ is $\infty$ you can also overcome any Coulomb-barrier. But I'm not totally sure about this one yet.

Comment: I brought these things up since I think they would be good to include in your answer. And I wasn't talking about the uncertainty principle. I am saying that saying two things are in the same place requires an infinite precision in measurement. This point is not too bad to remedy if you define a threshold so that we say they are in the same location, but I thought this should be mentioned as well

Comment: Absolutely, a point worth mentioning!